# Show day name on AM Chart instead of day number

Tags: jquery, amcharts

I am working on AM Charts and I need to show day names like SUN, MON, TUE on category field but I am unable to do it. I am able to show day numbers but no names. Kindly help.

Thanks in advance!!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll need to use [`dateFormats`](http://docs.amcharts.com/3/javascriptcharts/CategoryAxis#dateFormats) on `categoryAxis` for this. If you have a daily data, you might only need to override the format for "DD":

```
"categoryAxis": {
  // ...
  "dateFormats": [ {
    "period": "fff",
    "format": "JJ:NN:SS"
  }, {
    "period": "ss",
    "format": "JJ:NN:SS"
  }, {
    "period": "mm",
    "format": "JJ:NN"
  }, {
    "period": "hh",
    "format": "JJ:NN"
  }, {
    // overriding date format for daily data
    "period": "DD",
    "format": "EEE"
  }, {
    "period": "WW",
    "format": "MMM DD"
  }, {
    "period": "MM",
    "format": "MMM"
  }, {
    "period": "YYYY",
    "format": "YYYY"
  } ]
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
AmCharts.formatDate(new Date(2016,4,21), "EEE, DD MMM YYYY");
```

In am chart

```
Day of the month:
D = 7 (one or two digits)
DD = 07 (always two digits)  
Day of week:
E = 2 (single digit day of week)  
EE = 02 (two-digit day of week)  
EEE = Tue (3-letter abbreviation of the literal representation of the day of week)   
EEEE = Tuesday (full day of week name)
```

For more info https://www.amcharts.com/tutorials/formatting-dates/

In Case of charts

```
AmCharts.formatDate([new Date(2016,4,21)],shortDayNames);
```

It is used for Array of short versions of day names, used when formatting dates

> (But it works only if categoryAxis.parseDates is set to true)

Comment: Its not working, Can you please show me a working example ?